# Pivot a table SQL in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following table in Snowflake/SQL and want the resulting dataset to look like below.

I'm essentially trying to pivot the dataset

```
select * from 
(select top 100 p.TAG, p.PRIORITY, "'ON'","'OFF'" from 
(select *
from tab
order by datetime asc)
pivot(max(DATETIME) for STATE  in ('ON','OFF')) as p)
order by 'ON' asc;
```

Not sure on next steps. Any help appreciated.

Thanks

BEFORE

| DATETIME | TAG | PRIORITY | STATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.00am | ABC | 1 | ON |
| 1.15am | DEF | 1 | ON |
| 1.20am | ABC | 1 | OFF |
| 1.25am | ZYX | 1 | ON |
| 1.30am | ABC | 1 | ON |
| 1.35am | DEF | 1 | OFF |
| 1.40am | ABC | 1 | OFF |

AFTER

| DATETIME | TAG | PRIORITY | ON | OFF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.00am | ABC | 1 | 1.00am | 1.20am |
| 1.15am | DEF | 1 | 1.15am | 1.35am |
| 1.25am | ZYX | 1 | 1.25am |  |
| 1.30am | ABC | 1 | 1.30am | 1.40am |

Answer (score 0):

You can use below simple query to calculate on/off column. Use `group by` to group by selected columns and max() to calculate on/off columns.

```
select DATETIME ,TAG,   PRIORITY,
max(case when STATE='ON' then STATE else null end) ON,
max(case when STATE='OFF' then STATE else null end) OFF
from mytable
group by 1,2,3
```